# Assigning values via a Lambda Expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I am aware of the following quote:

> The reason is that a lambda expression can either be converted to a delegate type or an expression tree - but it has to know which delegate type. Just knowing the signature isn't enough.

Trouble is I am still stuck on how to resolve my problem.

Can someone tell if the below is at all possible?

```
bool isStaff = () => { return selectedPerson.PersonType == "Staff"; };
```

Error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type

I understand the error, but I really want to know how to fix this issue as I have rebounded off this error many times and simply not learnt to how properly use lamda expressions as far as value assignment is concerned.

Thanks for the quick replies fellas:

IMO, it would be awesome of the below was possible:

```
bool isStaff = (selectedPerson, bool) => { return selectedPerson.PersonType == "Staff"; };
```

Lol, I don't think that works but is beautiful in line code, to me that looks awesome and what I expect. The answers below seem to suggest otherwise lol!

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense to me. Lambda expresses some function (whether in the form of actual function or an expression), how do you expect to assign something like that to a `bool`? What should that do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the lambda returns a `bool` when it is evaluated, but it is not a `bool` itself.

You can do the following:

```
Func<bool> func = () => { return selectedPerson.PersonType == "Staff"; };
bool isStaff = func();
```

This assigns the lambda to a variable, which can then be used to invoke the lambda, and return the desired `bool` value.

Comment: This is the one that meets my visual eye! Also taught me how to do this now.

Answer (score 6):

```
bool isStaff = selectedPerson.PersonType == "Staff";
```

or

```
Func<Person, bool> isStaffDelegate = selectedPerson => 
                                         selectedPerson.PersonType == "Staff"; 
bool isStaff = isStaffDelegate(selectedPerson);
```

Comment: technically I would use the first half any day but it was worth a question or two on StackOverflow.com to try and learn something now. lame how the later is more work when the first half is simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

As the compiler says, you need to assign to a delegate or expression tree type. So for example:

```
Func<bool> isStaff = () => selectedPerson.PersonType == "Staff";
```

Now you haven't explained what you're really trying to do, or what `selectedPerson` is. The above will *capture* the `selectedPerson` variable - but you may *actually* want a `Func<Person, bool>` instead, as per the_ajp's answer.

Comment: it really does me irk me when lambda expressions have been marketed as a short hand syntax but in some scenarios it is anything but simple and straight forward.

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz: Well they're shorter than the alternatives - although I'm confused as to why you *prefer* the version in the accepted answer, using braces and a return statement, rather than the more concise version here.